"Graphing" calculator
Kinda a short one, but yeah.
Y=MX+C  is the equation we all learnt to represent a line... But can you Code Golf it?
Write a program that takes in a list in the format M, C, V, and then returns the first V worth of whole x values. V will always be 1 or greater, M and C can have any (float) value (inc 0).
Examples (these are in python format for readability, use any I/O method you want):
[2,0,5] -> [2,4,6,8,10]
[1,1,15] -> [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
[0.5,-1,1] -> [-0.5]
[0,0,5] -> [0,0,0,0,0]

Scored with Code-Golf (Least bytes wins), use any language :D

Please avoid cumberson I/O formats. Just let people decide how they want to take input and give output.

Yes sorry, I was only specifying Python Format for the examples to make it easier.

Now do Y=MX²+NX+C (or higher)…

Vyxal 3, 3 bytes
ɾ×+

Vyxal It Online!
Input in the form V, M, C as separate args

nice! FYI since yesterday, you can name your groups with the desired output, and it will tell you whether the program passed each test: Vyxal It Online!

well that's definitely something

APL (Dyalog 20.0), 5 bytes
Anonymous tacit infix function, taking V as left argument and [M,C] as right argument.
⍪⍤⍳⍛⊥

Try it online! (emulation due to old TIO version)
…⍛⊥ evaluate in mixed-base, but first pre-process the left argument as follows:
 …⍤⍳ expanding to the indices 1…V, and then:
  ⍪ transform into a column vector (matches up the entire [M,C] with each of 1…V)

Jeez that's concise, Adám!  ⍛ looks like a newer operator?  I don't think its on TryApl.org anyway; would you please give a little overview of what it does, or I guess how it differs from normal composition?

"pre-process the left argument" - as in X f g Y turns to (f X) g Y?

@Aaron Yes, that's exactly it. See APL Wiki and YouTube.

05AB1E, 3 2 bytes
Lβ

Two loose inputs in the order and format \$V\$ and \$[M,C]\$.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
L   # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input V]
 β  # Convert the second (implicit) input-pair [M,C] from a base-v list to a
    # base-10 integer for each v in the [1,V]-ranged list
    # (after which this list is output implicitly)


brainfuck, 43, 30 bytes
,>,>,[-<<[-<+>>+<]<[->+<]>>.>]

Try it online!
Takes M, C, V in ascii ordinals, some if not most implementations use unicode ordinals.
Doesn't work in floats.
Thanks to @WeirdGlyphs for -13 bytes. Also, this user gave me the explanation for the code.
Explanation:
,>,>,                            take (M C V)
     [                           while V != 0:
      -                              V minus 1
       <<[                           while M != 0:
          -<+>>+<]                       M minus 1; temp plus 1; C plus 1
                  <[->+<]            M = temp; temp = 0
                         >>.>]       print(C)


I'm not sure if my code will always produce the same output as your program, but I also tried to write it and found 30 bytes (31 if you can't go to the left of the first memory cell). Here's the code with some explanations.

@WeirdGlyphs That doesn't work if M is 0

That's weird, it seems to work for me. Here's an example. I started with 1, 1, 5 in order to easily copy-paste into the input box, then substracted 1 from M and C to get 0, 0, 5 in order to replicate the last example provided by the OP, I execute the code, and I add 48 to the result before printing in order to display it properly, and the result is what was expected. Can you provide an example where it doesn't work?

@WeirdGlyphs Wait, I confused that you assumed that M is always true, while in reality, V is the checking boolean, I get it now.

Desmos, 19 bytes
f(m,c,v)=[1...v]m+c

Try It On Desmos!
What better way to solve a "graphing" calculator problem... than to literally use a graphing calculator!

R, 15 bytes
\(m,c,v)m*1:v+c

Try it online! (Note- TIO doesn't yet support \ for function)

Haskell + hgl, 19 bytes
m#c=ft[m+c,2*m+c..]

Attempt This Online!
Ungolfed:
f m c v = take v [m+c, 2*m+c]


Nim, 57 bytes
proc f(m,c,v:float)=
  if v>0.0:f(m,c,v-1.0);echo (m*v)+c

Attempt This Online!

APL+WIN, 6 bytes
Prompts for input of v followed by m and then c
⎕+⎕×⍳⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Octave, 17 bytes
@(m,c,v)(1:v)*m+c

Try it online!
Basically the same code as Eonema posted in the answer in R.

Nekomata, 3 bytes
R*+

Attempt This Online!
Takes input in the order V, M, C.
R*+
R       [1,...,V]
 *      Times M
  +     Add C


Bash + common utilities, 27
jot -- $3 `bc<<<$2+$1` - $1

Try it online!

C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) with /u:System.Linq.Enumerable flag, 36 bytes
(m,c,v)=>Range(1,v).Select(i=>m*i+c)

Try it online.
Explanation:
(m,c,v)=>           // Method with two double and one integer inputs
                    // and IEnumerable<double> return-type
  Range(1,v)        //  Create an IEnumerable in the range [1,v]
  .Select(i=>       //  Map each value `i` to:
             m*i+c) //   Multiply `m` by `i` and add `c`


Forth (gforth), 35 bytes
: a 0 DO 2DUP OVER I * + + . LOOP ;

Try it online!
Just works with integers, not with floats. Modifies global integer stack state.

Uiua, 5 bytes
+×+1⇡

Try it: Uiua pad

Add

the product of

the range 1 to V
and M


and C




Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 13 bytes
Range@#3#+#2&

Try it online!

Ruby, 25 bytes
-2 bytes thanks to G B.
->m,c,v{(1..v).map{c+=m}}

Attempt This Online!

Charcoal, 9 bytes
Ｉ⁺×…·¹ＮＮＮ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order V, M, C. Explanation: Forms a range from 1 to V, vectorised multiplies it by M and vectorised adds C.
6 bytes by requiring input in JSON format:
Ｉ⁺×⊕…Ｎ

Try it online! Takes input in the order V, M, C. Explanation: Forms a range from 0 to V-1, increments it, then vectorised multiplies it by M and vectorised adds C.

PowerShell, 36 bytes
iex('1..{2}|%{{{0}*$_+{1}}}'-f$args)

Try it online!
The obvious solution would be something like for($i=1;$i-le$args[2];$i++){$args[0]*$i+$args[1]} for a whopping 50 bytes, mainly due to the $args elements.
Using iex (an alias for Invoke-Expression, which interprets a string as PowerShell), and the format operator -f, allows to golf 14 bytes from that.
Slightly ungolfed:
'1..{2} | % {{ {0} * $_ + {1} }}' -f $args
$args is an array which contains the three input values; they will be inserted into the string at {0}, {1}, {2}, respectively (the double {{ and }} escape the curly brackets required for the loop).
So with 2, 0, 5 as input, that would create the string
1..5 | % { 2 * $_ + 0 }
% is an alias for ForEach-Object, and $_ is the loop variable.
iex will then run this string as PowerShell.
Output is implicit.

Python, 40 39 35 bytes
lambda M,C,V:[C:=C+A for A in[M]*V]

-1 byte by tsh

-4 bytes by Albert.Lang

You may chang to c-m*~x to save a byte.

35 bytes using the walrus.

Excel 365, 35 bytes
Input M, C, V into A1:C1.
In any other cell, write the formula:
=MAKEARRAY(C1,,LAMBDA(x,y,x*A1+B1))


19 bytes: =A1*SEQUENCE(C1)+B1

Very nice! I was wondering what other array functions Excel had.

Tcl, 64 bytes
proc C {m c v} {time {lappend L [expr $m*[incr i]+$c]} $v
set L}

Try it online!

Japt, 4 bytes
õ!ìV

Try it here

JavaScript (Node.js), 32 bytes
m=>c=>g=v=>v?[c+=m,...g(v-1)]:[]

Try it online!

AWK, 30 bytes
{for(;i++<$3;)printf$1*i+$2FS}

Attempt This Online!
{for(;i++<$3;) # increment to V
printf         # print Y
$1*i+$2        # MX+C
FS}            # space between numbers


Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo), 45 bytes
my ($m,$c,$p)=@*ARGS;for 1..$p {say $m*$_+$c}

Attempt This Online!

You used arguments in your program, not stdin, please double-check your example before posting.

Zsh +coreutils, 24 bytes
echo $1\*{1..$3}+$2\;|bc

Try it online!
There's also a short solution using jot and setopt force_float but that would be unoriginal.

JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes
Expects (m)(c)(v) and returns an array of floats.
m=>c=>g=v=>v?[...g(v-1),m*v+c]:[]

Try it online!
Commented
m =>             // 1st function taking m
c =>             // 2nd function taking c
g = v =>         // g = recursive function taking v
v ?              // if v is not 0:
  [              //   update the output array:
    ...g(v - 1), //     append the result of a recursive call with v-1
    m * v + c    //     followed by the current value m*v+c
  ]              //   end of array
:                // else:
  []             //   stop the recursion

